# matlab - find nearby points of a lot of objects

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance

I have a number of objects that each have three matrices of distance between own points (x1-x1,x1-x2,x1-x3...;x2-x1,x2-x2,x3-x2...) also with y and z.

I want to find as many nearby points as possible, assuming rotation is not an issue.

I tried something. Since Matlab is supposed to work easy with matrices I am sure something is cumbersome but I don't know how to fix it.
For each object and it's mirror, and for each translation on each axes there is an xyz scenario:
(x1,y1,z1;x2,y2,z2;...)
So I am translating and mirroring one object a million times.

```
for m=1:object1
for n=1:object2
 for i=1:NumRows
 for j=1:NumRows2
  d_x(m,n,i,j)=obj(m).xyz(i,1)-obj(n).xyz(j,1);
  d_y(m,n,i,j)=obj(m).xyz(i,2)-obj(n).xyz(j,2);
  d_z(m,n,i,j)=obj(m).xyz(i,3)-obj(n).xyz(j,3);
  d_r(m,n,i,j)=sqrt(d_x(m,n,i,j)*d_x(m,n,i,j)+d_y(m,n,i,j)*d_y(m,n,i,j)+d_z(m,n,i,j)*d_z(m,n,i,j));
  if d_r(m,n,i,j)>=0 & d_r(m,n,i,j)<1.2
   d_r(m,n,i,j)=1.2-d_r(m,n,i,j);
  else
   d_r(m,n,i,j)=0;
  end
  sy(m,n)=sy(m,n)+d_r(m,n,i,j);
 end
 end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you start putting indices in variable names, think twice if they maybe should be a single variable. Here we have `d_x` `d_y` `d_z`. My recommendation would be to replace them by a single variable:

```
d_xyz(m,n,i,j,:)=obj(m).xyz(i,:)-obj(n).xyz(j,:);
```

And now to your next line, what you are calculating there is actually called a 2-norm. If you know the name, it's simple to shorten:

```
d_r(m,n,i,j) = norm(squeeze(d_xyz(m,n,i,j,:)),2);
```

Comment: I did not get the second suggested line. I used `d_r(m,n,i,j)=sqrt(d_xyz(m,n,i,j,1)*d_xyz(m,n,i,j,1)+d_xyz(m,n,i,j,2)*d_xyz(m,n,i,j,2)+d_xyz(m,n,i,j,3)*d_xyz(m,n,i,j,3));`.

Comment: What you are doing there, squaring each number and that taking the root of the sum, is exactly the definition of the 2 norm. It is also known as the euclidean distance. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: I get `Error using norm Input must be 2-D.`.

Comment: Understood your comment wrong, thought you did not understand the math behind. I actually forgot a squeeze in the code. `norm` does not work for inputs of size [1,1,1,1,3], here it requires a [3,1] vector. Updated my answer.

Comment: I do know that part of math but I do not program as much. I do little program lines and sometimes I try to improve them.